# bootstrap multiselect KnockoutJs - allBindings.has is not a function

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-multiselect

I have integrated bootstrap multiselect dropdown with KnockoutJs. When I load my page, I am getting following error in bootstrap-multiselect.js file:

**Uncaught TypeError: allBindings.has is not a function**.
Look at this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAY4a.png) for code in bootstrap-multiselect.js file for more information.

Please help me solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: wc to SO. Please help us help you by providing more information in the form of specific code (both js and html) that as per you, is causing this issue...

Comment: Upgrade your Knockout to the version 3 or higher.

Comment: Thank you f_martinez! Your solution worked for me! :)